# Need improve editor of magento Stackexchage

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I thought MA need to improve it editor feature.I have see `Stack overflow editor`,provide all new feature and upgrade it `code highlighter(Code Snapshot)`.

Some time  i have been magento stack exchange's  Code Snapshot is not work properly.

Please put your proposal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax highlighting](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11/syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no syntax-highlighting in Magento.stackexchange because the site is still beta. As soon as it graduates, adjustments would be done.